# How to create artificial microphone input in Linux?

Tags: linux, audio, linux-kernel, kernel-module, alsa

I'm working on an audio recognition project.

For testing, I'd like to be able to have a program:

- load audio data from a file
- provide it to the Linux kernel, *as if it were coming from a microphone*
- have any user-space program sampling the microphone be obtaining data sourced 
   from my file.

Is that possible in Linux without having to write a new kernel module?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: i guess that solution won't work .. but see my comment below.

this shoud be simple under linux.

here are the steps:

1. make a named pipe with mkfifo (mkfifo ~/audio_out.pipe)
2. cat the audiofile into this pipe (cat test.wav > ~/audio_out.pipe)
3. get the program you want to listen, to get input from this pipe. maybe you have to make a symlink for programs not flexible enough to read from any device.

I hope I got your question right.

Comment: well ... but I found something maybe helpful: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/adintool.1.html